# couldn't load xuggler version 5 error

Tags: maven, eclipse-luna, xuggler

i am trying to run a simple program using xuggler 5.4 with maven and eclipse-luna.
But it is showing me following error.

```
17:18:51.492 [main] ERROR com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader - Could not load library: xuggle; version: 5; Visit http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/faq/ to find common solutions to this problem
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no xuggle in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary0(JNILibraryLoader.java:268)
at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibraryLoader.loadLibrary(JNILibraryLoader.java:171)
at com.xuggle.ferry.JNILibrary.load(JNILibrary.java:161)
at com.xuggle.ferry.FerryJNI.<clinit>(FerryJNI.java:16)
at com.xuggle.ferry.Ferry.<clinit>(Ferry.java:25)
at com.xuggle.xuggler.XugglerJNI.<clinit>(XugglerJNI.java:19)
at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer.<clinit>(IContainer.java:1622)
at com.xuggly.App.main(App.java:8)
```

i used xuggler 5.4 version.

i also tried this with 5.2 version of xuggler
it is showing the same error.

following is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.xuggly</groupId>
  <artifactId>Transcode</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Transcode</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


<repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>xuggle repo</id>
   <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
   <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
   <version>5.4</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>




    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: You've set the `scope` of the xuggle-xuggler dependency to `test`, is that deliberate?

Comment: I am new in maven, i used maven only for xuggler. can u please tell me a little about scope and its values. and what value should give here in scope tag ??

Comment: try changing the value to `compile` - it might help. As for details on the scope it basically tells maven when this dependency should be available on the classpath (at compile time, or only while executing the tests etc). For more details see the following: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-dependency-scope

Comment: i used compile also, but it is showing same error, what else can i do ??  Not only compile i have tried all other values showing same error.

Comment: My problem is Solven, i created a simple java project, and add xuggler and slfj4 manually (i copied xuggler  from maven local repositoy). and there is not error. Thank you.